Suitescript 2.x Custom module script is not working with Render module
I'm trying to call a script with a button that I created on specific file type. It originally called a client script but I realized the render module is for server scripts only. I thought switching to a custom module would allow me to use the render module but I keep getting the same error I got with the client script. Is there another script type I should be using or is there something wrong with my code?
Error that shows up in the console
Custom module script:
/**
*name.js
*@NApiVersion 2.x
*@NModuleScope Public
*/

define(['N/record', 'N/render'], 

/**
* 
* @param {record} record 
* @param {render} render 
* @returns 
*/



  function (record, render) {

      function customButtonSendInvoice(transaction){
          console.log("The button is working.")
      }

      return{
          customButtonSendInvoice: customButtonSendInvoice
      }
  });

User Event script that creates the button:
    /**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 */
define(['N/ui/serverWidget', 'N/log', 'N/render'],
    /**
 * @param{serverWidget} serverWidget
 * @param{log} log
 * @param{render} render
 */
    (serverWidget, log, render) => {
        /**
         * Defines the function definition that is executed before record is loaded.
         * @param {Object} scriptContext
         * @param {Record} scriptContext.newRecord - New record
         * @param {string} scriptContext.type - Trigger type; use values from the context.UserEventType enum
         * @param {Form} scriptContext.form - Current form
         * @param {ServletRequest} scriptContext.request - HTTP request information sent from the browser for a client action only.
         * @since 2015.2
         */
        const beforeLoad = (scriptContext) => {
            try{
                const form = scriptContext.form;
                var transaction = scriptContext.newRecord.getValue({fieldId: 'tranid'});
                form.addButton({
                    id: 'custpage_send_invoice_button',
                    label: 'Send Invoice',
                    functionName: `customButtonSendInvoice("${transaction}")`
                }); 
                form.clientScriptModulePath ='SuiteScripts/BHM Customizations/name.js'
                
            }
            catch(e){
                log.error({
                    title: e.name,
                    details: e.message
                })
            }
        }
        
        return {beforeLoad }

    });


As Brett says, "as long as you're calling that from a server script" it should work.  But your screenshot looks suspiciously like the Chrome devtools, which means it's running as a client script.  The usual way to do this sort of thing would be to put your "working" code into a Suitelet, and call the suitelet from the client script.

The screenshot is from the console tab from the inspect menu on chrome. The custom module script is being called by a user event script. In my limited understanding both of those are server scripts. Why would it be running as a client script? I had experimented with Suitelets but I didn't like that it opened a new tab. Should I spend some more time on them?

The user event script is a server script.  The custom module script is a module that will be run in the context of whatever script calls it.  You say your custom module script is called by the user event script, but I don't see where - it's not included in your define.  If you're thinking that it's called by the user event because of the functionName parameter in the addButton function, that's not how it works.  What actually happens is that the user event looks for that function in the client script (specified in the form.clientScriptMopdulePath and binds that function to the button.

The user event runs at the time of loading the page (or, in fact beforeLoad as the name implies) and then exits.  It doesn't get called when you click the button.  What happens when you click the button is that the function from the client script (again, specified by the clientScriptModulePath) is called.  That can run client side APIs, or it can offload work by calling a server script.  Suitelet is easy to call by resolving the url (url.resolveScript), and opening that url with window.open or similar.  You can control whether it opens in a new tab by which function and options you use

There's nothing obviously wrong with your code. As long as you are calling that from a server script (which you should include) it should work.
However NetSuite has been picky about the formatting of the script type annotation. The issue may be as simple as adding spaces. So from:
/**
*name.js
*@NApiVersion 2.x
*@NModuleScope Public
*/

to
/**
* name.js
* @NApiVersion 2.x
* @NModuleScope Public
*/


I made the changes you suggested and did not get a different outcome. Ill edit my original post to include the User Event script that creates the button.
